# Paying by PayPal returns the customer to a manual Place Order page instead of completing order

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, place-order

I've just completed my first run through purchasing a product on a Magento 1.9.2.4
 CE site I've just been putting together. The payment gateway is PayPal Payment Pro.

When PayPal returns you to the site, after paying, you end up on a page that asks you to Place Order. It also allows you to change shipping methods, which changes the cost, even though the customer has just paid.

How do I change this so that paying completes the order?

Here is the dev site: http://www.gtechniq.high-speed.net.au

I can't think of any other e-commerce site that makes you take extra action to complete the order after you've paid. I suspect my client will have lots of payments in PayPal and no completed ordered in Magento, especially as you have to scroll the page down to find the Place Order button.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that, yes, it was  something simple and instead of deleting this, I'll give the answer for anyone else who can't find it: "Skip Order Review Step" should be set to Yes.

I had interpreted this as meaning something else, but removing it completes the order automatically (if you have Payment Action set to Sale) after you have completed your payment.